# Вычисление координат в матрице

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Есть 5x5 матрица квадратов в произвольной части экрана. Как найти координаты (x, y) в центре каждого квадрата?

[image]

Comment: сами что то пытались? Покажите ваш код, ваши попытки себе помочь

Comment: Взять размеры матрицы, ее координаты на экране и произвести необходимые вычисления.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
координатные оси вправо и вниз

l, t, r, b = координаты матрицы
s = ширина разделительной линии (отступы по краям ей тоже равны)
n, m = количество прямоугольников по вертикали и горизонтали

w = (r-l - s * (m+1)) / m
h = (t-b - s * (n+1)) / n

x0 = l + s + w / 2
y0 = t + s + h / 2

i, j = номера строки и столбца в 0-индексации

x = x0 + (w+s)*i
y = y0 + (h+s)*j
```

PS: Если значения (даже промежуточные) дробные, то при реализации алгоритма имеет смысл сделать всё одной формулой, чтобы умножение что до деления.

PPS: Если отступов по краям нет, то вместо `+1` надо использовать `-1`.

Comment: Зачем отдельно считать ширину и высоту без отступов, и потом делить зачем-то на`m` и `n`? Нельзя ли сразу ширину и высоту посчитать с учетом отступов:`w = (r-l) + s*(m+1)`и потом уже координаты центра `x0 = l + w/2` ...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99930/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-ampawd).